# Automating Python package release process

Tags: python, build, continuous-integration, pypi, python-packaging

I've just started an open source Python project that I hope might be popular one day. At the moment to release a new version I have to do a few things.

1. Test all the things.
2. Edit `mypackage.VERSION` variable, which `setup.py` imports from `__init__`
3. Build packages and wheels with `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
4. Write a changelog entry to `CHANGELOG` file
5. Commit my changes, echo some of that changelog
6. Tag that commit as a release, copy that changelog entry over again.
7. Drag in my built files so people can download them from the release
8. Use Twine to push the packages up onto PyPI
9. Test again on my staging server via PyPI.

If I had to sum up everything I hate about my project in nine bullet points, I think we'd be looking at a very similar list. The thing that cuts is that past me making up a new version number and writing the commit/changelog message, this is painfully dull.

Can I automate any of these tasks in such a way that I might be able to, for example, let GitHub CI do *everything* just from my commits?

I already have a decade of Python experience, and a bit of CI, but I'm very new to packaging Python and actively interacting with PyPI. I suspect I'm not the only person driven crazy by the manual repetition here, I'm just looking for tools (or services) that can make this process easier.

Comment: Is there a specific CI you have in mind? Depending on it an answer might look a lot different.

Comment: Or did you mean gitlab CI? because that exists out of the box.

Comment: Project is currently on GitHub, without CI. It's FOSS so anything that's free-for-FOSS would be fine. But I'm also completely fine moving this over to Gitlab and using their CI. That's where I do most of my paid work these days. If one or other makes what I'm doing here easier or better, *that's* what I want to hear about.

Comment: Ok. last question, is your step 9 test only an isntall from pyPI, or does it also re-run the test suite from step 1, or does it produce an artifact based on the downloaded lib, or something else?

Comment: The purpose of #9 is to test that the built package works as a package. So yes, currently just testing that I can `pip install` it, and it takes a while because PyPI is pretty slow to update IME. It could be done after #3 I guess - and that would save me uploading rubbish. Doing actual "does it work" tests are a bit trickier for me to automate because my "real" test harness is a commercial project that uses this project (it's a Django library), so I obviously can't include that in here. That has its own test CI.

Comment: Ok, I wrote a bunch. I can add/modify/explain some stuff if this is close enough to what you want.

Comment: Funny thing, I got a beta key for github actions (i.e. github CI/CD) yesterday. If it's of use to you I can see if I can translate the `gitlab-ci.yml` content into actions.

Comment: I hate to nag, but is there anything i can add to my answer to bring into an acceptable state for you?

Comment: @Arne I was leaving it unaccepted so it stayed on the bounty board as long as possible. Gets you more upvotes. Anyway, thanks for your help. You've already made an impact on how I deploy but I'm a little way off implementing your whole answer.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I didn't know that that's how it behaves. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following is my own opinionated take on your list. There is a certain range of automation you can achieve, and I'll try to provide a reasonable starting point, and then some hints on how you can go further from there.

---

## CI without CD

Adopting this part should already get rid of most of the annoying manual work, and you can automate away more and more as the need arises. If you're not comfortable maintaining a good amount of CI code, you should start here.

Things you'll need are a CI (as you already noted) and a package manager. Something you won't get around is pushing your changes and a new tag with git, so parts of step 5 and 6 remain manual.

### Package management

I'll use [poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/) to keep things concise and because I like it<sup>[1]</sup>, but there are also [other options](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#next-steps). This will take care of steps 2, 3, 7, 8, and the unlisted step 10, "update my dependencies and test them for compatibility", which is incredibly annoying as soon as it turns out to be a problem.

The bad news when using poetry is that you'll need to move all packaging configuration into a new file, `pyproject.toml`. The good news is, that you don't need a separate `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, `MANIFEST.in`, or `requirements.txt` any more, since [`pyproject.toml`](https://snarky.ca/clarifying-pep-518/) is a provisional standard for packaging and other tools, and poetry also has a [walkthrough](https://poetry.eustace.io/docs/pyproject/) on how to port over all the relevant info.

Once the setup is ready, the new deployment workflow would be:

```bash
$ poetry update           # update dependencies, may be skipped 
$ poetry version patch    # bump version
Bumping version from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3
# finalize git stuff, e.g. add -u, commit -m 'v1.1.3', tag v1.1.3, push
$ poetry publish --build  # build and publish to PyPI
Building my_django_lib (1.1.3)
 - Building sdist
 - Built my_django_lib-1.1.3.tar.gz

 - Building wheel
 - Built my_django_lib-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl

Publishing my_django_lib (1.1.3) to PyPI
 - Uploading my_django_lib-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl 100%
 - Uploading my_django_lib-1.1.3.tar.gz 100%
```

This should already be a lot shorter than what you're currently doing. If you always execute the exact same git commands, are not afraid to automate a push, and take good care of your `.gitignore` file, feel free to add something like this function to your `~/.bashrc` and call it instead:

```bash
git_cord () {
  version=$(grep pyproject.toml -e '(?<=^version = ")(.*)(?=")' -Po)
  git add -u
  git commit -m "${version}"
  git tag "${version}"
  git push -u origin "${version}"
}
```

### Getting started with gitlab-CI

The CI can in principle handle everything surrounding the deployment process, including version bumping and publishing. But the first requires that your CI can push  to your repo (which has annoying side effects) and the latter that it can publish to your PyPI (which is risky, and makes debugging the CI a pain). I think it's not unusual to  prefer to do those two steps by hand, so this minimal approach will only handle step 1 and 9. More extensive testing and build jobs can be included afterwards.

The correct setup of a CI depends on which one you plan to use. The [list for github](https://github.com/marketplace/category/continuous-integration) is long, so I'll instead focus on gitlab's builtin CI. It's free, has very little magic (which makes it comparably portable), and the binaries for the CI runners are [open, free, and actually documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/), so you can debug your CI locally or start and connect new runners if the free ones don't cut it for you.

Here is a small `.gitlab-ci.yml` that you can put into you project root in order to run the tests. Every single job in the pipeline (skipping setup and install commands) should also be executable in your dev environment, keeping it that way makes for a better maintainer-experience.

```yaml
image: python:3.7-alpine

stages:
  - build
  - test

packaging:
  stage: build
  script:
    - pip install poetry
    - poetry build
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - dist

pytest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pip install dist/*.whl
    - pip install pytest
    - pytest
```

Setting up the `build` and `test` stage like this handles steps 1 and 9 in one swoop, while also running the test suite against the installed package instead of your source files. Though it will only work properly if you have have a src-layout in your project, which makes local sources unimportable from the project root. Some info on why that would be a good idea [here](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/) and [here](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/).

Poetry can create a src-layout template you can move your code into with `poetry new my_django_lib --src`.

### The changelog

While there are tools out there that [automatically create a changelog](https://github.com/vaab/gitchangelog) from commit messages, [keeping a good changelog](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) is one of those things that benefit greatly from being cared for by hand. So, my advice is no automation for step 4.

One way to think about it is that the manual `CHANGELOG` file contains information that is relevant to your users, and should only feature information like new features, important bugfixes, and deprecations.

More fine grained information that might be important for contributors or plugin writers would be located in MRs, commit messages, or issue discussions, and should not make it into the `CHANGELOG`. You can try to collect it somehow, but navigating such an `AUTOLOG` is probably about as cumbersome as sifting through the primary sources I just mentioned.

So in short, the changelog-related parts of step 5 and 6 can be skipped.

---

## CI with CD

Adding CD doesn't change too much, except that you don't have to release by hand any more. You can still release with poetry in case the CI is down, buggy, or you don't want to wait for the pipeline to release a hotfix.

This would alter the workflow in the following way:

- everyday work
- write code (can't avoid this one yet)
- document progress in commit messages and/or MRs (I prefer MRs, even for my own changes, and squash all commits on merge)
- push to gitlab / merge MRs
- on release
- create a tag, run `poetry version` and maybe `poetry update`
- write release notes in `CHANGELOG`
- push to gitlab

This addition to the former `.gitlab-ci.yml` file should work right away if you [supply the secrets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-environment-variables) `PYPI_USER` and `PYPI_PASSWORD`:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release
  
[...]  # packaging and pytest unchanged

upload:
  stage: release
  only:
    - tags
    # Or alternatively "- /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/" if you also use non-release
    # tags, the regex only matches tags that look like this: "v1.12.0"
  script:
    - pip install poetry
    - poetry publish -u ${PYPI_USER} -p ${PYPI_PASSWORD} dist/*
```

---

Some useful links:

- [`.gitlab-ci.yml` documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/)
- [list of predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), this is where most of gitlab CI's obscurities lie
- [the long version](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/d78c9ec09776642313934c76e5803e5e#file-gitlab-ci-yml) of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` template, with additional stages that may or may not be useful to you. It expects a src layout of your code.

  - `lint`: [type checking](http://mypy-lang.org/), [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/), and [code style](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
  - `security`: checking [your own code](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [your dependencies](https://github.com/pyupio/safety) for valnuarabilities
  - `release.docs`: public gitlab pages section where docs are served that are created automatically [based on your docstrings](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html)
  - The `build` stage creates a wheelhouse from the `poetry.lock` file that can be used for installing dependencies later in favor of PyPI. This is a little faster, saves network bandwidth, and asserts the use of specific versions if you want to debug, but might be overkill and requires the use of a poetry pre-release.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>Among other things, poetry also 1) handles the virtualenv for you, 2) creates a hashed lockfile in case you need reproducible builds, and 3) makes contribution easier, since you only have to run "poetry install" after cloning a repo and are ready to go.</sub></sup>

Comment: Giving anybody (even the repo host) ***my*** credentials for PyPI seems... *weird*. I'm not saying it's wrong, but it makes me uneasy. I'm considering setting up a secondary account and giving it publish permission on PyPI. Sound redundant or sensible?

Comment: Only the owner of a repo can see the values of secret variables in the UI, and if it's set to "protected" it will only be accessible in protected branches, which only merges triggered by the owner should be able to trigger. As long as you pay attention that contributors don't add `echo ${MY_KEYS}` to your `on: master` jobs, your secrets *should* be safe. Then again, I have seen "ci-users" in many big projects that are used as exactly that kind of security barrier. They have a publish token but not the keys to the repo, and are used to authenticate pipeline runs and write warnings into channels

Comment: In short, sounds sensible to me, even if you would trust gitlab / github with your credentials.

Comment: @Oli You can create **tokens for individual packages** on PyPI and then use that instead of your login credentials if it makes you feel any better.Look [here](https://pypi.org/help/#:~:text=API%20tokens%20provide%20an%20alternative,projects%20associated%20with%20that%20account.) for more information.

Comment: Minor correction: The `poetry version` command requires a "bump rule" to actually bump the version, else it will simply output the current version. The three main ones are "major", "minor", and "patch" - so, most commonly: `poetry version patch`, which will bump a version number from x.y.z to x.y.z+1.

Answer (score 5):

I automated this for one of my open-source tools.
It‘s all in the file manage.py:
https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize/blob/master/manage.py

My project uses poetry for uploading to pypi, so this looks a bit different but should be a good starting point. It also manages the changelog and creates all releases.

`python manage.py version` steps:

- prompts for version number and checks validity
- updates the __version__.py file
- updates the pyproject.toml file used by poetry
- searches for a section `## WIP` in changelog.md and replaces it with current version and todays date.

`python manage.py publish` steps:

- reads the current version
- reads the changes listed for this version from the changelog
- creates a git tag
- pushes to github (with tags)
- builds and publishes to pypi
- creates a github release with the version number as name and the changes from the changelog as description

The scripts asks for confirmation for each step so things don't get out of hand and prompts for your github and pypi passwords as soon as they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Arne's answer:

### Changelog management

There are several tools managing automatically the Git tag + Changelog + choose the next version number (determining whether the change is a patch, minor or major change)

I particularly like [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release), that simply requires that you conform to [Angular Commit Message Conventions](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-commit-message-format).

This is a must, especially if you're managing an open source project. This will both help you maintain a very clean Git history and an accurate Changelog for your project.

### GitLab CI implementation

If you're using GitLab, there are CI templates that might help you implement all of your requirements with very few efforts.

I'm thinking of [to-be-continuous](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/), a fully open-source comprehensive collection of professional templates (20+) covering a vast range of languages, tools and technologies.

They have a [template for Python](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/ref/python):

- supports the main dependency management tools (poetry, setuptools, pipenv, requirements file),
- pytest and other unit testing tools,
- pylint,
- bandit, safety and other SAST tools,
- and finally supports [the release process](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/ref/python/#py-release-job) as you described it

They also have a [template for semantic-release](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/ref/semantic-release) and guess what: it works with the Python template (means semantic-release is determining the next version number, and the Python template is actually doing the release).

As a result, your requirements would be implemented on GitLab with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
# included templates
include:
  # Python template
  - project: "to-be-continuous/python"
    ref: "5.0"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci-python.yml"
  # semantic-release template
  - project: "to-be-continuous/semantic-release"
    ref: "3.0"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci-semrel.yml"

# secret variables
# (define the variables below in your GitLab group/project variables)
# GIT_USERNAME+GIT_PASSWORD or GIT_PRIVATE_KEY: Git creds for Git push operations

# variables
variables:
  PYTEST_ENABLED: "true"
  # disable release from sem-rel as Python is performing it
  SEMREL_RELEASE_DISABLED: "true"
  SEMREL_INFO_ON: "prod"
  PYTHON_RELEASE_ENABLED: "true"

# your pipeline stages
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - publish
```

/!\ check for newer template versions. Either from the reference documentation, or with their [Kicker](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/kicker) tool, an interactive wizard that helps you generate your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Enjoy!