# python conda release automation including changelog

Tags: python, pip, conda, changelog, spotless

In the gradle/JVM world there is the awesome plugin: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless-changelog

Is there any similar public solution available I am currently missing when building pip or conda packages?

This: [Automating Python package release process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628064/automating-python-package-release-process) refers to using poetry, but is not nearly as fully-fledged as spotless-changelog and seems to require some manual setup/scripts.
I know that there is a python package for validating the keepachangelog format https://pypi.org/project/keepachangelog/ available - but do not see any integration like spotless-changelog.

Are manual steps required to chain it up? Or am I overlooking a great & already existing tool for such an automated process similar to spotless-changelog?

Answer (score 0):

https://zestreleaser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ so far looks like the closest match